# PrintWriter not writing to .java file

Tags: java, printwriter, file-writing

The code compiles and no errors are thrown. However, the text is not printing to my .java file. I tried printing to a .txt file, but that isn't working either. The file I am trying to print to is in the same directory as my Main class. I know that the 2 most common causes of PrintWriter not working are not closing the PrintWriter and not having the correct path. I don't think either one is the issue here, but I may be overlooking something. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is my code with irrelevant bits left out:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                Gui gui = new Gui();
                gui.createAndShowGUI();
                gui.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        //System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Basket.java");
        PrintWriter pw = null;

        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(file);
            pw.println("hello there");
            pw.flush();// tried with and without flushing;
            // System.out.println(pw.checkError());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (pw != null) {
                pw.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No exceptions? Is the file just nonexistent after execution?

Comment: Try checking if the file exists or not. 

Use something like this:

`if (!myFile.exists()) { myFile.createNewFile(); }`

Comment: Your code to write to the file does work as expected (I just ran it myself), but I'm not sure what the preceding code is doing... have you stepped through your code to see whether you actually reach the file writing part? Maybe you're getting stuck in the GUI init part and the file writing part is not being executed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I needed to manually refresh my project directory view in Eclipse. Shortcut: F5.